# CS50 blur function implementation

Tags: c, function, nested-loops, rgb, cs50

I wrote the code for the blur function, and the output of it is incorrect:

```
{10,40,70
110,120,130
200,220,240}
```

Above is the 3x3 test image of pixels. All pixels are red. Performing blur on the middle pixel `120` gives an average of `145` using my code and not `127` (the correct answer). For those unaware of cs50 use;

[link](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/4/filter/less/)

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < width; column++)
        {
            int sumRed = 0;
            int sumGreen = 0;
            int sumBlue = 0;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                {
                    if (abs(row - i) <= 1 && abs(column - j) <= 1)
                    {
                        sumRed += image[i][j].rgbtRed;
                        sumGreen += image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                        sumBlue += image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }

            float averagered = (float)sumRed / (count);
            float averagegreen = (float)sumGreen / (count);
            float averageblue= (float)sumBlue / (count);
            image[row][column].rgbtRed = round(averagered);
            image[row][column].rgbtGreen =  round(averagegreen);
            image[row][column].rgbtBlue =  round(averageblue);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

My code is implemented above. My plan is to stop at each pixel using the first two loops then use another two loops to iterate over the image from start and check if a pixel is within 1 row and 1 column of the pixel we stopped at.

Comment: You must build another image. Otherwise you'll be filtering with pixels that have already been processed. Also the inner loops should iterate (at most) a 3x3 sub-grid with either 4, 6, or 9 pixels.

Comment: do you mean a temp image?

Comment: Yes, you need a temp image

Comment: You need a second array to hold the results.  If you modify the top-left pixel value, then when you calculate with the top-middle pixel, you're using a different number (the new calculated number instead of the original input value).  Either create a local array on the fly and copy it to the input array once the calculation is complete or revise the interface to the function so that the caller provides the output array too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your implementation:

- you must use a separate set of pixels as the source and destination of the blur function, otherwise you reuse modified values for the pixels on the right and below the current one.
- your implementation uses 4 nested loops on the whole matrix, for a total time complexity of **O(N<sup>4</sup>)**, which will be slow on moderately large images. You should only iterate on a 3x3 area for the inner loops and add tests for the edge cases.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <bmp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]) {
    RGBTRIPLE (*copy)[width] = malloc(sizeof(*copy) * height);
    if (copy == NULL) {
        perror("cannot allocate image copy\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    memcpy(copy, image, sizeof(image[0][0]) * width * height);

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < width; column++) {
            int sumRed = 0;
            int sumGreen = 0;
            int sumBlue = 0;
            int count = 0;
            for (int r = row - 1; r <= row + 1; r++) {
                for (int c = column - 1; c <= column + 1; c++) {
                    if (r >= 0 && r < height && c >= 0 && c < width) {
                        sumRed   += copy[r][c].rgbtRed;
                        sumGreen += copy[r][c].rgbtGreen;
                        sumBlue  += copy[r][c].rgbtBlue;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            image[row][column].rgbtRed   = round((double)sumRed   / count);
            image[row][column].rgbtGreen = round((double)sumGreen / count);
            image[row][column].rgbtBlue  = round((double)sumBlue  / count);
        }
    }
    free(copy);
}
```

You could avoid allocating the space for a full copy of the image and only allocate working space for 3 rows, at the cost of extra copying.